# run time error 3464 mismatch in crietria expression

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to verify if a site selected from a cascading combobox (named cboSite) matches any of the various site names in the column "within 10" in the table named SLA. if so i want it to calculate a function i have come up with the code. The first bit of the expression is executed however if i choose a site that is not in the within 10 column in SLA then my elseif statement is not excuted.

```
Private Sub txtRTF_Click()
If Not ISNull (DLookup("Within10", "SLA", "Within10 = '" & Me.cboSite.Value & " '")) Then
Me.txtRTF = DateAdd("h", 2, [Date Fault Lodged])
ElseIf Not ISNull (DLookup("10_50", "SLA", "10_50 = '" & Me.cboSite.Value & " ' ")) Then
Me.txtRTF = DateAdd("h", 4, [Date Fault Lodged])
ElseIf Not ISNull (DLookup("50_80", "SLA", "50_80 = '" & Me.cboSite.Value & " ' ")) Then
Me.txtRTF = DateAdd("h", 8, [Date Fault Lodged])
ElseIf Not ISNull (DLookup("80_100", "SLA", "80_100 = '" & Me.cboSite.Value & " ' ")) Then
Me.txtRTF = DateAdd("d", 2, [Date Fault Lodged])
ElseIf Not ISNull (DLookup("Over100", "SLA", "Over100 = '" & Me.cboSite.Value & " ' ")) Then
Me.txtRTF = DateAdd("d", 10, [Date Fault Lodged])
End If
End Sub
```

What i am trying to achieve is very similar to when creating login access in ms access. when someone enters the username and password it checks in the table to see if the username and password are correct then allow use of forms etc.

I am not trying to check if the value is Null or empty or incorrect. I am trying to verify that the value selected is in the table SLA in the column Within10 if so execute `Me.txtRTF = DateAdd("h", 2, [Date Fault Lodged])`or else check in the next column in the table SLA.

Comment: can you change  "  '  "  to "'" ? e.g without the space.

Comment: The statement `"Within10 = '" & Me.cboSite.Value & " ' "` will add a blank space after the value, because of `" ' "`, if the value of `Me.cboSite.Value` is `"foo"`, it will become `"foo "`. I think you should remove the spaces here (`"'"`)

Comment: Plus, your `DateDiff("hm", 0, 8, [Date Fault Lodged])` doesn't seem like a valid syntax for me. I don't know much about `access-vba`, only worked with `excel-vba` so I might be wrong here, but I think you cannot use `"hm"` as interval, plus `[Date Fault Lodged]` doesn't seem like a valid argument.

Comment: yes thanks for pointing that out i was an error should have been "n" instead of m
i have a few changes and edited it into my post

Answer (score 1):

Check for *Null*:

```
Private Sub txtRTF_Click()

    If Not IsNull(DLookup("Within10", "SLA", "Within10 = '" & Me.cboSite.Value & "'")) Then
        Me.txtRTF = "Something"
    End If

End Sub
```

Your:

```
DateDiff("hm", 0, 8, [Date Fault Lodged])
```

doesn't make sense at all, so read up on the syntax; it is not to guess what you are trying to do with this.

Comment: I fairly new on Access and i was trying to experiment with equations
i will be using this instead 
Me.txtRTF = DateAdd("h", 2, [Date Fault Lodged])

Comment: I am fairly new on Access and i was trying to experiment with equations
Diff2dates("hn", 0, 8, [Date Fault Lodged]) i just changed the diff2dates with the datediff statement the 8 in this case is adding 8 hours instead it equated  days, so changed the 8 to (0.334) the reason i put a 0 was because without the zero i was getting a result of over a million hours
however i will be using this instead after i can correct my if statement
Me.txtRTF = DateAdd("h", 2, [Date Fault Lodged])

Comment: There is no _Diff2Dates_ function in VBA.

Comment: yes there isnt it was i was provided a module code that used diff2dates
however for the purpose of the current equation i will be using dateadd

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you want to display in `txtRTF`, the current `type mismatch` error is in the `IF` statement: you are checking a `Variant/String`, which is not a Boolean. What you want is to check if the result of the lookup is empty:

```
If DLookup("[Within10]", "SLA", "[Within10] = '" & Me.cboSite.Value & "'") <> Empty Then
    Me.txtRTF.Value = "..."
End If
```

Comment: seems i have my code wrong
what i am trying to achieve is to check if the value in Me.cboSite is in the column Within 10 in the Table